# How to call a UDF in master database on a linked server

Tags: sql-server, remote-server, udf

I am unable to call a UDF in a Linked Server.

Here's my T-SQL code:

```
DECLARE @Phone_Digits_Input varchar(12);
DECLARE @Phone_Min_Max_Input varchar(5);
DECLARE @Phone_Digits_String varchar(10);
DECLARE @Phone_Min_Max_String varchar(5);
DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(500);
DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500);
DECLARE @phone_digits varchar(10);

SET @Phone_Digits_String = 'phone_digits';
SET @Phone_Min_Max_String = '10-10';

SET @SQLString = N'SELECT @phone_digitsOUT = RemoteServer.master.dbo.myUDF(@Phone_Digits_Input, @Phone_Min_Max_Input)';
SET @ParmDefinition = N'@Phone_Digits_Input varchar(10), @Phone_Min_Max_Input varchar(5), @phone_digitsOUT varchar(10) OUTPUT';

EXECUTE RemoteServer.master.dbo.sp_executesql @SQLString, @ParmDefinition, @Phone_Digits_Input = @Phone_Digits_String,
     @Phone_Min_Max_Input = @Phone_Min_Max_String,
    @phone_digitsOUT=@phone_digits OUTPUT;
SELECT @phone_digits;
```

When I run it, I get a message:

> Msg 344, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Remote function reference 'RemoteServer.master.dbo.myUDF' is not allowed, and the column name 'RemoteServer' could not be found or is ambiguous.

How can I fix the issue please?

Comment: OPENQUERY would probably work.

Comment: Have you tried removing the server name from the string (change "RemoteServer.master.dbo.myUDF(" to "master.dbo.myUDF(". Because your EXECUTE includes the remote server name, you should be OK

Answer (score 0):

I got the server name wring! The UDF was i a different database! Sorry for my confusion.
The final code is below:

```
DECLARE @Phone_Digits_Input varchar(12);
DECLARE @Phone_Min_Max_Input varchar(5);
DECLARE @Phone_Digits_String varchar(10);
DECLARE @Phone_Min_Max_String varchar(5);
DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(500);
DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500);
DECLARE @phone_digits varchar(10);

SET @Phone_Digits_String = 'phone_digits';
SET @Phone_Min_Max_String = '10-10';

SET @SQLString = N'SELECT @phone_digitsOUT = dbo.MyUDF(@Phone_Digits_Input, @Phone_Min_Max_Input)';
SET @ParmDefinition = N'@Phone_Digits_Input varchar(10), @Phone_Min_Max_Input varchar(5), @phone_digitsOUT varchar(10) OUTPUT';

EXECUTE MyServer.MyDB.dbo.sp_executesql @SQLString, @ParmDefinition, @Phone_Digits_Input = @Phone_Digits_String,
       @Phone_Min_Max_Input = @Phone_Min_Max_String,
       @phone_digitsOUT=@phone_digits OUTPUT;
SELECT @phone_digits;
```

Thank you.